# Array formula having unique values for Data Validation dropdown without using helper column

Tags: arrays, excel, validation, unique, formulas

I am trying to create an array defined name to enter into a data validation dropdown without using any helper columns in the sheet.

I have a table containing one of the column headers called 'List' which contains names of employees. The names may be duplicated, hence I want to extract only the unique names and put them into a data validation dropdown. I don't intent to use VBA and don't want to use any helper columns to drag the formula down to populate the unique names. On pressing F9, the formula should return unique values in an array like this:

```
{tom;fawad;george;jane;mario;flavia}
```

The table column looks like this:

```
List Column 2  Column 3 .....
tom
fawad
george
george
jane
mario
flavia
mario
george
fawad
```

Right now the formula is returning only one value when pressing F9 key.

```
=INDEX(list,IFERROR(SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(list,list,0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(list)))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(list))),""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(list)))),""))
```

I think it may require TRANSPOSE or SUBSTITUTE function to split the returned values across dropdown rows. Someone had demonstrated something like this, but I don't remember the link now.

Anyone know how to create a unique names array formula that I can simply enter directly into a Data Validation dropdown?

Comment: A UDF will easily help this situation and make it easy. Is that OK?

Comment: I agree with @MacroMarc. Even if an array formula could be sculpted, the nature of its open-ended list makes it impractical.

Comment: I was just looking at this, and something didn't work as I expected in that a UDF doesn't seem to be able to work for me in the Data validation source. Might have to take that helper column... Array formula might work, but too tough for me. Sorry...

Comment: i can code a VBA macro to do the same. but its a proprietary client file and and xlsx. they dont need any macros. since it is densely populated, they also dont want any helper sheets or helper columns as the results from this master file is being pulled into another application. :(

An array formula for a DV dropdown would be good. In the Index function, i get the number of rows correctly as an array, but Index is somehow not pulling those names unless i put the formula in a cell and drag it down other cells.

I know its possible as someone on a forum or blog had demonstrated its possibility.

Comment: @Jeeped what did you mean by "the nature of its open-ended list makes it impractical"? – sifar786 1 hour ago

Comment: You don't know how many entries you are retrieving, hence open-ended list. Formulas are horrible for this because they need to know how a maximum of many entries to look for. What you typically end up with is the correct entries and a large number of blank rows because you had to ask the formula to return as many as possible and the duplicates errored out.

Comment: @Jeeped, i suppose that's why someone as i said earlier was using SUBSTITUTE, REPLACE etc along with TRANSPOSE etc to replace the blanks or TRIM etc.

but my question is, is it possible to have such an array formula created without using Helper columns to list its contents?

Comment: Short answer:no. Long answer: noooooooooooooooooo.

Comment: so no virtual helper columns?